# Hard Code Value for @Html.EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My MVC 3 application needs to **create new users**.

I want to hard code the ApplicationId for the ApplicationId text box in the view.

Does anyone know how to do this?

The create method does not fetch any data:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}


  <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicationId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ApplicationId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicationId)
        </div>
```

**Update**

There is an option. To use a hidden field.

```
    @Html.Hidden("ApplicationId", "ep006964-83a8-4f40-a569-d2d3296f005b")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, in the controller action serving this view, you simply set the corresponding property on your view model:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var model = ... go and fetch your model from somewhere
    model.ApplicationId = "some hardcoded value";
    return View(model);
}
```

Now the `EditorFor` will display the correct value. There's no way to force the value in the view. The whole point of editor templates is that they use the values that are set for your view model.

Comment: I cannot fetch data in the create method

Comment: Erm, pardon me? I am not sure I understand your comment and its relation to the topic. You cannot fetch data? I guess you will first have to tell us more about this data. Then about the fetching, etc... so that we can make sens out if.

Comment: I just uploaded my create method. As you can see it does not fetch any data

Comment: In other words I am not returning anything

Comment: I still don't understand your words. You are not returning anything? What are you talking about? Your controller action passes a model to this strongly typed view, isn't it? Otherwise using strongly typed helpers such as Html.EditorFor is meaningless. I guess you will have to show your controller action because I have no clue what you are talking about.

Comment: It is a strongly typed view, but it's not passing anything. Since this is the create view. If this was the edit, details or delete view, I would be able to pass the model. But this is the create method.

Comment: Now that you have updated your question I see your Create method. But there is something terribly wrong with it. You are not passing any model to the view. And yet you are using EditorFor in this view. Is this your `[HttpPost]` action? Does this Create action take a model as argument? Anyway, if you use EditorFor your controller action should absolutely pass a model to this view. Otherwise you have some serious problems.

Comment: The views were created by the controller automatically using scaffolding. There is nothing wrong. Everything is working. I need to hard code the value in the view. Your method works only for Edit, Delete and Details. Do you know how to hard code the value in the create view?

Comment: No, there's no way to hardcode the value in the view. The EditorFor uses the value of the property that is passed as model to this view. So you will have to modify this property.